# getting error 503 service unavailable while fetching html from amazon

Tags: php, curl

```
function fetchMinAmazon($product)
{


    $base = "https://www.amazon.com.tr/s?k=" . str_replace(' ', '+', trim($product));


    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);

    if (curl_errno($curl_handle)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl_handle);
    }
    if (isset($error_msg)) {
        echo $error_msg . "<br>"; // The requested URL returned error: 503
    }
    curl_close($curl_handle);


    curl_close($curl_handle);

    ...
```

I wrote a script that fetches data from amazon running on the client, but when I put the code on the server, it started giving the error 503 service unavailable but this error only happens while I fetch html from amazon. Can anyone help?